# Multiple tcp services on the same port

Tags: linux, tcp, firewall, iptables, markers

I'm working on a project where some clients (embedded linux systems) needs to connect to a main server using so far at least two protocols: HTTPS and SSH. One of the requirement is that only one flow is allowed from every client to the server, so I've to found a way to make the two services works on the same port.

One solution that I was thinking about is to use the iptables markers: on the client side mark the packets for SSH with 0x1, the packets for HTTPS with 0x2 and then on the server side, based on the marker, redirect the packets to the right service listening on the local interface. Is it an acceptable solution? Are the markers kept by the network routers or is only something working locally on the same machine for iptables?

And anyway, if you can advice about a different solution, of course it's welcome!

Comment: Markers are not a TCP/IP thing, so I don't think there's any way these could be sent to the network.

Comment: What I think you need to do is make a connection to a single port, and then send something in your protocol that says whether it's SSH or HTTPS, and the serverfor your protocol  will then forward to the appropriate service.

Answer (score 3):

More for other users finding this question in the future:

https://github.com/yrutschle/sslh has what you might need. I haven't used it (yet) but planning on it.
From the Github site:
sslh -- A ssl/ssh multiplexer

sslh accepts connections on specified ports, and forwards them further based on tests performed on the first data packet sent by the remote client.

Probes for HTTP, SSL, SSH, OpenVPN, tinc, XMPP are implemented, and any other protocol that can be tested using a regular expression, can be recognised. A typical use case is to allow serving several services on port 443 (e.g. to connect to SSH from inside a corporate firewall, which almost never block port 443) while still serving HTTPS on that port.

Hence sslh acts as a protocol demultiplexer, or a switchboard. Its name comes from its original function to serve SSH and HTTPS on the same port.